# How can I confirm this kind of dialog?

Tags: software-installation, wine, microsoft

During installing wine this dialog appeared

[image]

I have no idea, how to confirm this dialog? Neither enter nor any other key, ctrl+C or clicking OK with the mouse seems to work. I just want to continue installation. How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press tab until you reach "OK".Then press Enter